# Removing focus and gaining focus on a control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to remove focus from an item in a ListBox when clicking on a button, then give focus to an item in an other ListBox. Is there something to remove focus? And how can I give focus to an other ListBox again, or even better, its' selected item?

I have tried to use the `SelectionChanged` property but the focus is all off when moving items in List's around.

Comment: Depends on what kind of focus you want to change. Also there is no way of removing focus, only reassigning focus. I would advice you to read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx).

Comment: This would be a really good place to start. Head down to the Focus Section of the page. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010.aspx#focus 

The logical focus is probably what you care about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a really good place to start. Head down to the Focus Section of the page.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010.aspx#focus

The logical focus is probably what you care about